# Path to me returning incorrect value on unzipped AppleScript application

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-catalina

So here's a peculiar situation. I created an AppleScript application that relies on the `path to me` command. After saving as AppleScript Application it runs perfectly. However, if you archive/zip the file, then unzip and run again after downloading/emailing or on another computer, the `path to me` is incorrect.

For example, I created a super simple app to test this:

```
set myPath to (path to me as text)
display dialog "myPath: " & myPath
```

Save the application and run it from the Finder by double clicking it.

Mine reports correctly: `myPath: Sierra:Users:joshbooth:Desktop:Test.app:`

Zip/Unzip the file on my other laptop and run again.

The result is `myPath: 429EF755-2646-4249-A428-666D454E9DAD:d:Test.app:`

Option + click and drag to create a new copy in the same directory then run again:

result: `myPath: Macintosh HD:Users:joshbooth:Downloads:Test 2.app:`

Any ideas what is happening or how to prevent it?

Comment: I was unable to duplicate your issue by moving a copy from a Mojave mini to a Catalina Air, with and without running it before zipping.  You might try code-signing the app or making the script in the app bundle read-only.

Comment: As a quick fix, you might try sending the app in a disk image (dmg) rather than zipping it. Are the two laptops running the same OS? You might be looking at differences in the version of the zip utility, or some opaque change in AppleScript across OSes that's causing confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I've no real "answer", but my info is too big for comments (and no one else has chimed in)...

While there may be other cases, at least one cause is a downloaded zip being marked "quarantined" which results in OS X expanding it into a temp "/private/var/folders" location (with the complex folder name you see, as well as the expanded item being quarantined and actually on a read only file system).

So, it is the "download" biting us, which we can see in the "com.apple.quarantine" attribute of the app, and zip, in a terminal window with "xattr -l /Users/johndoe/Downloads/Test.app" (like "com.apple.quarantine: 0083;5f20ce0e;Safari;BFABF751-2ACD-4B6F-9952-9A87D45AC9D4"), and remove it with "xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Users/johndoe/Downloads/test.app".

Getting (POSIX path of (path to me as string)) within the expanded app would have shown something like /private/var/folders/lh/9hl01d1n2knckzj0bxdb22lr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/429EF755-2646-4249-A428-666D454E9DAD/d/Test.app before removing the quarantine flag.

Unfortunately, given the temp path is locked, the app itself can't remove the flag with "xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /private/var/folders...", getting "xattr: [Errno 30] Read-only file system", so idea what we can do with this info, but these are my findings.

**One good note:** moving or copying the expanded app to another folder leaves the quarantine flag set, but updates the "path to me" resolution, which is a bit inconsistent, and confusing, by OS X in my opinion (debatably defeating this quarantine flag pattern if it was intentional), but a useful workaround.